# the layout does not show up

Tags: android

I am new in developing android and i am very interested in android development. yesterday i downloaded and installed android studio and watched tutorials on simple game development. but the problem is that the android layout here doesn't show up i have no idea how to fix it, can somebody help me? I'm really stuck in here :(

this android something in here (pointed in red arrow) does not show up in my android studio

[image: image1]

second image shows my android studio

[image: image 2]

and another problem is that nothing shows up in my themes

here is another problem, my themes are all empty

[image: image 3]

Comment: it's because your gradle sync failed.resolve your gradle error and it's work

Comment: Show us your layout code and try to sync your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be Gradle build error here. Try the following:

1. Go to *Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files*
2. Then *Build -> Rebuild Project*

Answer (score 0):

This is error when syntax gradle layout
1- Go to Build -> clean project
if it is good OK 
OR
2- Go to Gradle Folder
and open build gradle(Model App) file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7rxA.png)
you need here to take care and sure of all compile and implantation
from here 
[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html)

after that make syntax